# What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the triangle number having 500 divisors but I keep getting this error. How to resolve it.

```
    import math
#I make a list of first 300 prime numbers
    def compute():
      z=[]
      prime = [True for i in range(1990)]
      p=2
      while(p*p<=1990):
        if(prime[p]==True):
            for i in range(p*p,1990,p):
                prime[i]= False
        p=p+1

      for p in range(2,1990):
        if (prime[p]==True):
            z.append(p)

      return(z)
#for counting the number of factors. Here is where I face a problem in the code      
    def countfactor(n):
      initial= n
      factor=1

      for i in range(0,n):
          if z1[i]<=math.sqrt(n):
             power=0
             while(initial%z1[i]==0):
                 initial=initial/n
                 power=power+1
             factor=factor*(power+1)


      if initial>1:
          factor=factor*2

      return(factor)
#function for providing triangle number to the countfactor() function      
    def compute1():
        i=1
        while(True):
            triangle=int(i*(i+1)/2)
            factors =countfactor(triangle)
            print(factors)
            if factors>500:
                print(triangle)
                break
            else:
                i=i+1

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        z1=compute()
        compute1()
```

The actual result should be 76576500 but I am getting the error  "list index out of range". Please explain the error and how to resolve it.

Comment: Hi there--it looks like you've posted a sample of code and an expected/desired behavior. However, it doesn't look like you've tried to use a debugger to step through your code to understand what it's doing. Please do so first, as it will either resolve your question, or allow you to provide more details that will help someone answer the question.

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. At bare minimum, add the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

I really have a hard time following your code. Why are you trying to find primes?

This is my solution in Python3:

```
import math

# Function that gets rectacle number by number
def get_rectangle_number(i):
  result = (i * (i + 1)) / 2
  return result

# Function that gets all divisors of a numbers
def divisorGenerator(n):
    large_divisors = []
    for i in range(1, int(math.sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            yield i
            if i*i != n:
                large_divisors.append(n / i)
    for divisor in reversed(large_divisors):
        yield divisor

# Init variables
number = 0
rectangle_number = 0
divisors = 0

# While the results has been found, keep searching
while divisors < 500:
  # Loop number
  number += 1

  # Get Rectangle number
  rectangle_number = get_rectangle_number(number)

  # Check count divisors
  divisors = len(list(divisorGenerator(rectangle_number)))

  # Debug
  print('Recatacle number: ', rectangle_number)
  print('Count divisors: ', divisors)

print('Solution:' ,rectangle_number)
```

[Online example](https://repl.it/repls/WateryBasicGnudebugger)